# Unable to process http delete request using powershell curl command

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\> $postParams = @{eventId='235'}
PS C:\> curl -Method DELETE -Uri http://localhost:8080/eventlist/api/v1/events -Body $postParams
curl : Error deleting event
At line:1 char:1
+ curl -Method DELETE -Uri http://localhost:8080/eventlist/api/v1/events -Body $po ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], Web
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

However, if I am trying to delete like

```
curl -Method DELETE -Uri http://localhost:8080/eventlist/api/v1/events?eventId=235
```

it works

Why is not working in the first way using `$postParams` ?

Comment: please see the correct command executed without missing the cutoff

Comment: can we please not tag these with "curl" since these are not *real* curl commands?

Comment: So you can tell from the expection that you're using Powershell's alias "curl", which really calls the Invoke-Webrequest cmdlet. Is that what you're intending? Or are you trying to call a real curl binary?

Answer (score 1):

```
This is not working

    PS C:\Users\> $postParams = "{eventId='$eventId'}"
    PS C:\Users\> Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri "http://localhost:8080/eventlist/api/v1/events" -Body $postParams

Invoke-WebRequest : Error creating event
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri "http://localhost:8080/eventlist/api/v1/even ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

This is working

```
PS C:\> Invoke-WebRequest -Method DELETE -Uri 'http://localhost:8080/eventlist/api/v1/events?eventId=235'


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : Event deleted successfully
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Content-Length: 26
                    Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
                    Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 12:27:46 GMT
                    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

                    Event deleted successfully
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Content-Length, 26], [Content-Type, text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1], [Date, Mon, 20 Feb 2017
                    12:27:46 GMT], [Server, Apache-Coyote/1.1]}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 26
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

It's failing because DELETE isn't a POST command.

*The code below is untested.*

To recreate the `DELETE` in PowerShell, your syntax needs to be:

```
$eventId=235
Invoke-WebRequest -Method DELETE -Uri "http://localhost:8080/eventlist/api/v1/events?eventId=$eventId"
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

This relates to the commandline app curl, not the PowerShell `curl` which is an alis for `Invoke-WebRequest`

It's failing for two reasons, The first one is that DELETE isn't a POST command. The second, is that you're trying to pass a PowerShell object into a commandline application.

*The code below is untested.*

To recreate the `DELETE` in PowerShell, your syntax needs to be:

```
$eventId=235
&curl -Method DELETE -Uri "http://localhost:8080/eventlist/api/v1/events?eventId=$eventId"
```

A `POST` command *could* be like this (depending on your endpoint):

```
$eventId=235
$postParams = "{eventId='$eventId'}"
&curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d $postParams 'http://localhost:8080/eventlist/api/v1/events'
```

Note, the body is a json string, not a PowerShell object.

Comment: In response to your second point:
No he's not - he's passing it into the poorly chosen alias for Invoke-Webrequest, which should expect to deal with powershell objects.

Comment: Good point, @GodEater. Forgot about the alias. WIll completely amend my post and strikethrough the bad parts!

Comment: No strikethrough in Markdown - have marked the edit & original

Comment: the post request is not working still i tried .. please see above answer

Comment: @Star123 - a DELETE request isn't a POST request. See this answer for a morfe compelte explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/299696/1368849

Comment: yeah thanks i got it . So DELETE I am trying it the one explained by you.But the second part i a trying to understand is now using POST i am trying to update a existing eventId which is not working

Comment: I want to understand why even POST is nt working even though my goal is to update something using POST

Comment: Try specifying the header, as in my original answer and also specifying the  content type. Also, you're specifying DELETE with POST data. YOu'd need to send a POST request.